# How to total currencies in FreeMarker?

Tags: java, freemarker

How can I tabulate data in FreeMarker while still keeping precision and [not losing cents due to double of float reprensations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3730019/why-not-use-double-or-float-to-represent-currency)?

```
<#assign totalSalaries = 0>

<#list employees as employee>
    <#assign totalSalaries = totalSalaries + emplpoyee.salary>
</#list>

${totalSalaries?string.currency}
```

Personally, I prefer to use longs and keep everything in cents but I couldn't find an easy solution to convert that to a currency value. Either way, if I'm using `long` or `BigDecimal` (it's easy to convert long with cents to BigDecimal) how can I guarantee that the total salaries printed out won't lose any cents due to precision errors of doubles or floats? In other words, how does FreeMarker decide what type of variable total is defined as?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FreeMarker does calculations (and the numerical type conversions needed as part of that) with the `ArithmeticEngine`, which is a configuration setting. The default of that setting is `BigDecimalEngine`, which converts everything to `BigDecimal` before doing anything with them, and keeps the results as `BigDecimal` as well. So at least with the default you won't lose any digits.

Comment: Do you know where this is documented? I looked for a while and couldn't find anything so it would be great to see where I missed it ;)

Comment: If you go through the configuration settings in the API, you can bump into it... surely it needs some more mentions. I will look into it.

Comment: Thank you, I found it. Yes if it's all possible I would recommend adding this somewhere on the website rather than just the API. In any case thank you again, it's very much appreciated. By the way I find FreeMarker to be a very amazing templating engine!! Awesome work!!